# Probability problem - Jackpots

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The rules of the final round of King's Lottery in Byteland are simple:

The player starts to draw balls from an opaque bag containing $a$ red balls, $b$ green balls and $c$ blue balls initially.
After the player draws the ball, the ball is not returned into the bag.
The player continues the process until he collects all $a$ red balls, or all $b$ green balls, or all $c$ blue balls.
The player wins the Gold Jackpot if he collects $a$ red balls, Silver Jackpot if he collects $b$ green balls, or Bronze Jackpot otherwise. Given $a$,$b$ and $c$, calculate the probabilities of winning each jackpot.
For example:

$a=1,b=2,c=3$,then $P(G)=\frac{7}{12},P(S)=\frac{4}{15},P(B)=\frac{3}{20}$

$a=1,b=1,c=1$,then $P(G)=\frac{1}{3},P(S)=\frac{1}{3},P(B)=\frac{1}{3}$

**My attempt**

I tried several times to solve this question. I think that I should common outcomes- all different arrangement of balls drawn from the bag and I calculated with repetition of permutation formaula: $\frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!b!c!}$. It determines denominator of fraction of probability.

**Need to help**

I couldn't find desired outcomes (numerator of fraction). Please help me to find desired outcomes.

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: @V013 I couldn't find the number of desired outcomes.

Comment: First solve the simplified version of the problem with just two colors of balls.